# How to determine which one is my default instance in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, instance

I have two instances in my server and I want to know which one of them is the default. Can you, please, point out ways I can recognize it. 
By saying a default instance I mean the one that listens for 1433.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

login in to your server and run this

```
 SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')
```

for sql server 2008 and above if it returns null then it's a default instance else named one

> **InstanceName**: Name of the instance to which the user is connected.
>
> Returns NULL if the instance name is the default instance, if the
>   input is not valid, or error.
>
> NULL = Input is not valid, an error, or not applicable.
>
> Base data type: nvarchar(128)

[Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Another one using `SEVERPROPERTY()`,

Run the below code

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')


SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

if both returns same value ie machine then it's your default instance else
the first one return with your machinename\instance name

**After your edit**

if you want to check the SQL server service which listens to port 1433. Then you have to check that in SQL server configuration manager. Check-in SQL server network configuration in that protocols for SQL server and click properties for TCP/IP and see the port used under IP addresses

Answer (score 2):

> By saying a default instance I mean the one that listens for 1433

Even a `named instance` can be configured to listen on `1433` port, but it still be a `named instance`.

To your question about knowing the port:

You can see what port is used **now** by your instance looking at the first rows of `SQL Server error log`, using GUI (`Management` -> `SQL Server Logs`), `xp_readerrorlog` or just opening `error log` using any text editor, Notepad for example.

So here you see one of my named instances that listens on `8853` for user connections and on `58490` for `DAC`

[image]

Or you can use `Configuration Manager`/`registry` entry for the same thing, you find the port under `Server Network Configuration` -> `Your Instance` -> `TCP/IP` like this:

[image]

The difference is that when you are looking at the `errorlog`, you get the port currently in use, and when you are looking at `Configuration Manager`/registry, you see the last configured value that can be currently in use or that will take place only after server `restart`, if it was configured but server was not restarted.

Comment: Alternatively, you can issue the following T-SQL query:

    select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port
    from sys.dm_exec_connections
    where net_transport = 'TCP'

Comment: @Thomas Rushton This cannot guarantee you with the info about configured port at any time, for example, all my connections just now use Shared Memory, so your query doesn't return anything, but the port is still configured

Comment: Good point, should have added a disclaimer on that!